# Different results on CPU and GPU

Tags: c++, cuda, double, gpu, nvidia

I implemented the same algorithm both on CPU and GPU using `C++` and `CUDA C`. In order to check if the results are correct I check if the 2 arrays of double calculated by both are the same with a precision of 1.0E-8 . And the result is that the 2 arrays are not the same. Is it possible to have different results because I'm working on two different entity or there might be some errors in my code?

I have to increase to 1.0E-3 to consider them equal!

Comment: Errors in your code. I've validated my cuda code to under 1e-12 floating point precision.

Comment: Is it short enough you could post it?

Comment: @ChristianSarofeen I ' ll try. 1 minute

Comment: What is the largest magnitude in the resulting array?  An epsilon of `1e-3` is incredibly small if your results are on the order of `1e12`.

Comment: I wish I could help you, but there isn't much in that code block I understand.

Comment: @MooseBoys my results are in the order of 1e-3 and 1e-4

Comment: The probable source of your problem is in the very first sentence of your question: "I implemented the same algorithm both on CPU and GPU". Rarely, if ever, will a non-trivial serial CPU algorithm be correct if directly moved to parallel execution on a GPU. There are only two barriers to a good GPU implementation- correctness and performance (in that order). It sounds like you have fallen at the first hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `dev_s` is thread local, you're going to have multiple threads writing to the same memory location here:

```
dev_s[i] = dev_s[i-1] + 0.5*(dev_matrix[index]+dev_matrix[index-1]);
```